# Filtering input data as it is read

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

One thing which is quite tedious with producing pgf plots is preparing or the raw data for pgf. Specifically, making the data set smaller to avoid the memory cap.

Generate some dummy data in R:

```
nPoints <- 10^6
df <- data.frame(seq(nPoints), cumsum(runif(nPoints, 0, 1)))
fwrite(x=df, file="data.dat", sep=" ", col.names=F)
```

Plotting `data.dat` directly results in a capacity exceeded error on my machine:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=6177416].
```

I thought it would be possible to filter the input data directly by doing something like,

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
    \addplot+[only marks] table [
                x index={0}, 
                y expr={ifthenelse(mod(\coordindex, 10000) == 0, \thisrowno{1}, NaN)},
                unbounded coords=jump,
             ] {data.dat}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However this just loads the whole data file and then displays the specified points instead of loading only the specified points. The `pgfplotstable` package offers `\pgfplotstabletypeset[every nth row={integer}[shift]{options}]` which looks useful. However it isn't clear what the `options` should be in order to delete rows from the read data, and whether the typesetting happens during or after data is read.

Is it possible to read only selected lines of a file with `pgfplotstable` and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort answer: Give to Caesar what is Caesar's. LaTeX is not to manage huge amounts of data. Even if you can reduce the data in the LaTeX side, as you are using R, data reduction should be done in the R side. Not only could be faster, but also easier.

Longer answer: On the other hand, R can also make plots even with huge amounts of data (if that could be sometime useful is another issue ...). With `knitr`, all R calculus are done at compilation of the main document but without overloading the TeX engine. And this will be done updating the graph only if the data changed (except if you use `CACHE=FALSE`).

A disadvantage could be (or not) that  R plots by default have not the LaTeX style (other fonts, different ticks in axis, etc.), but using the tikzDevice (`dev='tikz' option  with knitr) are true LateX graphs. The downside is that then R is also exposed to LaTeX limitations, so you can choose whether represent many thousands of points with R style or only a maximum of few thousands with the LaTeX style.

A  two-page example:

[image]

MWE.Rnw (compiled with Rstudio):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,parskip}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F>>=
set.seed(4) 
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(A=1:50, B=cumsum(runif(50, 0, 1)))
fwrite(x=df, file="data.dat", sep=" ", col.names=F)
@

If instead of tikz plots: \bigskip\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
    \addplot+[only marks] table [
           x expr=\thisrowno{0}, 
           y expr=\thisrowno{1}
             ] {data.dat}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

You can live with raw R plots ...

<<echo=F>>=
plot(df$A,df$B,xlab="",ylab="",col="blue", pch=19,cex=2)
     # ,axes=FALSE,      ylim=c(-2,32),xlim=c(-2,52)) 
@

\newpage
..  and R-tunned tikz plots ...

<<Rplot2,echo=F,dev='tikz'>>=
plot(df$A,df$B,xlab="",ylab="",col="blue",
     pch=19,cex=2,axes=FALSE, 
     ylim=c(-2,32),xlim=c(-2,52)
     ) 
axis(1, tcl=0.75, cex.axis=2.5)
axis(2, las=1, tcl=0.75, line = 0, cex.axis=2.5,labels=seq(10,30,10), at=seq(10,30,10))
axis(3, tcl=0.75, labels = FALSE)
axis(4, tcl=0.75, labels = FALSE)
box()
@

\newpage 

Then you can choose plot 15000 points without tikz: 

<<echo=F>>=
df2 <- data.frame(A=jitter(rep(1:50,300),10), B=jitter(rep(1:30,500),10))
fwrite(x=df2, file="data2.dat", sep=" ", col.names=F)
@

<<Rplot3b,echo=F>>=
# This plot does not work with tikz
plot(df2$A~df2$B,xlab="",ylab="",col="blue",cex=.1)
@

Or some more reasonable, like {\em only} 2/3 of points, with tikz: 

<<Rplot3,echo=F,dev="tikz">>=
df3 <- df2[sample(nrow(df2), 10000), ]
plot(df3$A~df3$B,xlab="",ylab="",col="blue",cex=.1)
@

\newpage

Or only the 0.2\,\%,  by random sampling:

<<>>=
df3 <- df2[sample(nrow(df2), 500), ]
@
<<Rplot4,echo=F,dev="tikz">>=
plot(df3$A~df3$B,xlab="",ylab="",col="blue",cex=.5)
@

Or by sistematic sampling: 

<<>>=
df3 <- df2[c(TRUE,rep(FALSE,50)), ]
@

<<Rplot5,echo=F,dev="tikz">>=
plot(df3$A~df3$B,xlab="",ylab="",col="blue",cex=.5)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just want to point out that 1. If R was sufficient, I'd be using that. pgf/tikz is quite an effort to prepare. Nothing else I've seen (R, Matlab, Python, Julia, ...) comes close to the cleanliness tikz/pgf. 2. And more to the motivation of my question: data preparation is easy, but consider that different axis scaling's require different kinds of filtration, not to mention sampling of periodic signals. The ideal workflow of generate + wrangle data in one environ. -> plot in another is broken with an intermediate step requiring generation of new data file that need tweaking outside pgf.

Comment: @algae  That is the point. There are not intermediate steps here. The example show that all can be done with only one file, in only one  step, even generating tikz figures. Note that only the first graph used the external   `data.dat`  for comparison with your approach  (moreover, internally generated on the fly, so mainly irrelevant for the human workflow). With respect cleanliness, a far I can see, the 1st and 3th plot have the same quality. Best plotting software is a very subjective issue, but  in this case is not a R vs Tikz dilemma. It could be also R using  Tikz.