# How to plot several large data in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, overleaf

I want to plot 16 data (the size of each data is 150 kb) by pgfplot and ***LuaLatex*** on the ***Overleaf*** website. But I could not have the pdf result.

There is an error:**Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a LaTeX error, or a large number of high-res images or complicated diagrams.**

And also I put the **log file** [here](https://gofile.io/d/xFFNIf).

Please let me know how I can solve the problem.

Thank you.

==========================================

[Here](https://gofile.io/d/F72Qty) is my data and my code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
%
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
%For rung by LuaLatex
%\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -    interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot post/.append style={mark=none,line width=0.8pt}}
\pgfplotsset{cycle list/RdYlGn,
cycle list/OrRd,
cycle list/PiYG,
cycle list/Dark2}
\pgfplotsset{every  major tick/.style={black}, every  minor tick/.style={black!60}}
\begin{axis}[
%
xmin=7.9,
ymin=3.99,
xmax=16.2,
ymax=5.4,
xtick distance=1.0,
ytick distance=0.2,
minor x tick num={1},
minor y tick num={1},
%
y tick label style={
/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,/tikz/.cd
},
x tick label style={
/pgf/number format/.cd,
fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,/tikz/.cd
},
%
%Changing y axis Unite
y filter/.code={\pgfmathdivide{#1}{1000000}},
%
tick label style={font=\small},
xlabel style={font=\small,xshift=-0.2cm,yshift=0.1cm},
ylabel style={font=\small,yshift=-0.1cm,xshift=-0.1cm},
ylabel={TDO Frequency (MHz)},
xlabel={Field (T)},
%
legend style={font=\footnotesize,at={(0.49,-0.2)},anchor=north,legend columns=2},
%
axis background/.style={shade,top color=gray!60,bottom color=white},
%
restrict y to domain=3.99:5.4,
restrict x to domain=7.9:16.2
]
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=1 of PiYG] table [x={Field_356}, y={Counter_356}] {356.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{356}$, $\theta$ = 38.8}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=3 of PiYG] table [x={Field_357}, y={Counter_357}] {357.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{357}$, $\theta$ = 38.8}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=1 of OrRd] table [x={Field_358}, y={Counter_358}] {358.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{358}$, $\theta$ = 49.0}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=3 of OrRd] table [x={Field_359}, y={Counter_359}] {359.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{359}$, $\theta$ = 49.0}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=1 of Dark2] table [x={Field_360}, y={Counter_360}] {360.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{360}$, $\theta$ = 59.3}
 %=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=3 of Dark2] table [x={Field_361}, y={Counter_361}] {361.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{361}$, $\theta$ = 59.3}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=4 of Dark2] table [x={Field_362}, y={Counter_362}] {362.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{362}$, $\theta$ = 69.5}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=9 of RdYlGn] table [x={Field_363}, y={Counter_363}] {363.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{363}$, $\theta$ = 69.5}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=8 of RdYlGn] table [x={Field_364}, y={Counter_364}] {364.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{364}$, $\theta$ = 79.8}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=7 of RdYlGn] table [x={Field_365}, y={Counter_365}] {365.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{365}$, $\theta$ = 79.8}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=6 of RdYlGn] table [x={Field_366}, y={Counter_366}] {366.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{366}$, $\theta$ = 90.0}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=5 of RdYlGn] table [x={Field_367}, y={Counter_367}] {367.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{367}$, $\theta$ = 90.0}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=4 of RdYlGn] table [x={Field_368}, y={Counter_368}] {368.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{368}$, $\theta$ = 100.2}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=3 of RdYlGn] table [x={Field_369}, y={Counter_369}] {369.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{369}$, $\theta$ = 100.2}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=2 of RdYlGn] table [x={Field_370}, y={Counter_370}] {370.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{370}$, $\theta$ = 110.5}
%=======================================================
\addplot+[index of colormap=1 of RdYlGn] table [x={Field_371}, y={Counter_371}] {371.dat};
\addlegendentry{C$_{371}$, $\theta$= 110.5}
%=======================================================
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Consider if  pgfplots is the best approach to plot large amounts of data.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/551546/11604

Comment: Also, blindly filtering data can be dangerous: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248723/plot-large-data

Comment: (Tom from Overleaf Support here.) When your project times out due to this, the easiest way is probably externalizing the `pgfplots` into a separate project or projects, and then download the PDF and upload into the proper project, or link the output PDF between the projects (that's possible too). This would allow you to split the document into several smaller ones that wouldn't time out.

Comment: @yo' Thank you so much for your response. But I have the error:  **"Timed out. Sorry, your compile took too long to run and timed out. This may be due to a LaTeX error, or a large number of high-res images or complicated diagrams.
"**. So, I have updated my question and also put the **log file**.

Comment: @yo' Could you show me an example of how to solve the problem?